# Required Validation Not working For DropdownList in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image]

```
    Below View Code. when i click on  Create button without  Selecting  Activity. it is not showing validation message. i am using Required attribute in Model Class

        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TransactionTypeID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
           <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TransactionTypeID, new SelectList(ViewBag.GetT, "TransactionTypeID", "TransactionType"), "--Select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TransactionTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
          <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActivityID, new SelectList(ViewBag.GetA, "ActivityID", "ActivityName"), "--Select--", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
        </div>


//Controller code
  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<TransactionTypeMaster> T = new DATransactionTypeMaster().GetListAll();
            ViewBag.GetT = T;

            List<ActivityMaster> A = new DAActivityMaster().GetListAll();
            ViewBag.GetA = A;

            return View();
        }
```

Can Any One Help on this. Need To Know Where i m going Wrong
when i click on  Create button without  Selecting  Activity. it is not showing validation message. i am using Required attribute in Model Class

Comment: Do you have the relevant scripts included (`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`)

Comment: Are you using attribute `[Required]` in the view model or trying with html validation attribute `required`?

Comment: I am using Required attribute in Model

Answer (score 3):

try giving the default '--Select--' options in your drop downs a value of 0.

In your model, make sure your drop down value is set to '[Required]' and also give it the attribute:

`[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Must Select A Value")]`

basically letting it only accept values > 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you TransactionTypeID is int, make that Nullable that would fix this issue. Currently it doesn't work because by default it might be sending zero as a value by using null, it would send null when user doesn't touch this field.